# Is a guitar body made out of mahogany generally lighter than a body made out of alder ?

Tags: guitar, instruments, construction, lutherie

I know that each piece of wood is different and two similar pieces of a same essence will have different weight.

But in general, for the same body shape and size which wood essence will tend to give a lighter body ? Mahogany or alder ?

Comment: Mahagony is a heavy wood.

Answer (score 8):

Mahogany guitars are generally heavier, with alder being quite light. Because of this, alder gives a light bright sound, and Mahogany gives a deeper Les-Paulier sound.

Of course it depends what sort of guitar the wood is used in. Semi-hollowbodies and semi-acoustics are generally a bit lighter than solid-body guitars.

Comment: I have an Ibanez SAS36FM, which is a Strat style guitar on a mahogany body. The combo is really nice because the wood gives it a very solid low end and the single-coils keep the fidelity and harmonics very alive.

Comment: I love mahogany strats! They take the boring out of them :D.

Comment: That it does. Mine has a low-end similar to John Entwistle's bass sound - it rings like tapping on a low-E piano string.

Comment: -1 for completely unfounded tonewood speculations. The wood of the guitar body has no measurable influence on the amplified sound of the guitar.

Comment: @RichardMetzler I've heard arguments on both sides of this fence.  Do you have a reputable source to back that claim up?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger : ["Physics of the Electric Guitar"](https://www.gitec-forum-eng.de/the-book/) by Prof. Manfred Zollner goes into a lot of detail (and some snarky diatribes about ignorant journalists and snake oil salesmen) on the issue in chapters 7.8 and 7.9.

Answer (score 6):

Warmoth has pretty great description of different woods' characteristics.

Go to: https://warmoth.com/guitar-body-woods. There's a ton of info about tone, weight and color.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't much matter whether you're talking about guitars, xylophones, or coffee tables.  Here is a chart of densities of hardwoods: [Wood Density Chart | Workshop](https://cedarstripkayak.wordpress.com/lumber-selection/162-2/)

Alder is listed at 400 - 700 kg/m³  (26 - 42 lb/ft³)

The various species of Mahogany range from 500 - 850 kg/m³ (31 – 53 lb/ft³)

There is substantial overlap between 500 - 700 kg/m³ (31 - 42 lb/ft³), so it's quite possible to have a particular piece of alder that's more dense than a particular piece of mahogany, but alder is on average less dense than mahogany.